# MediaPlayerLauncher cannot open file in wp8 irregularly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

to record an AAC file i'm using this code:

```
dev = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenForAudioOnlyAsync();
dev.AudioEncodingFormat = CameraCaptureAudioFormat.Aac;
IStorageFolder applicationFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var dataFolder = await applicationFolder.CreateFolderAsync("data", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
outputFile = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync(audioFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
var stream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
await dev.StartRecordingToStreamAsync(stream);
```

I stop the recording through a Click Handler with

```
  await dev.StopRecordingAsync();
```

Now i'll open the File

```
  MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();
  mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri(outputFile.Path, UriKind.Relative);
  mediaPlayerLauncher.Location = MediaLocationType.Data;
  mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();
```

Usually this will work: it'll play the file right away - everything as exepted.
But with about 20% of my test-cases the MediaPlayerLauncher will open and prompt:

```
"Sorry, we can't play this file on your phone"
```

When I try to open the same item again and again, eventually it'll play after a while.

Anyone has an idea what i can do about it?

Thanks.

Comment: `StopRecordingAsync` does not close `outputFile`... basically you wait for the GC which is bad practice... so sometimes the file is not closed yet when you try to play it...

Comment: any idea how i can close the stream: using `stream.FlushAsync(); stream.Dispose();` after `dev.StopRecordingAsync();` will still break the player

Comment: Same thing is happening with me.When I try repeatedly,eventually it works